# Denying user access to php.ini file with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Because we have some custom configuration in our php.ini file we apparently have to store it in the root dir of our site & hence any user would be able to see it.

How I can I block people accessing it via their browser for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put this in your `.htaccess` :

```
<FilesMatch "php.ini">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

It denies access to anyone trying to reach `php.ini`.

Edit: Allow and Order are deprecated in Apache 2.4. You should use `Require all denied` instead.

```
<FilesMatch "php.ini">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you for actually not using a deprecated method. It seems like 90% of answers use Allow and Order :(

Comment: Well, this answer is 5y old, Apache 2.4 wasn't widely used yet.

Comment: Yeah, but there are posts from last month where deprecated methods are being suggested still ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is inserting something like this at the start of php.ini file:

```php
/***************DO NOT ALLOW DIRECT ACCESS************************************/
if ( (strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] ), strtolower( basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) !== FALSE ) { // TRUE if the script's file name is found in the URL
  header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden' );
  die( '<h2>Forbidden! Access to this page is forbidden.</h2>' );
}
/*****************************************************************************/
```